# @ExceptionHandler method doesn't work when BindingResult parameter present in handler method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am validating a field(User) using javax validation api.

User :

```
@Data
public class User {

    public String name;
    @Min(18)
    public int age;

    public User(String nameString, int age) {
        super();
        this.nameString = nameString;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

Handler method in Controller Class:

```
@RestController
public class ControllerMain {

    @PostMapping("userdata")
    //Here is BindingResult !!
    public void validdata(@Valid @RequestBody User user,BindingResult bindingResult) {
        
    }
        
}
```

ControllerAdvice Class for Exception Handling

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

    @ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentNotValidException.class, HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
    public void invalidinput() {
        
        //This should be printed on console but its not.Kindly help!
        System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
    }

}
```

If I remove the BindingResult argument from handler method in Controller Class 'Invalid Input' is printed on the console. Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Spring MVC specification.

[1.3.3. Handler Methods > `@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.13/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody):

> You can use `@RequestBody` in combination with `javax.validation.Valid` or Spring’s `@Validated` annotation, both of which cause Standard Bean Validation to be applied. By default, validation errors cause a `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, which is turned into a 400 (BAD_REQUEST) response. Alternatively, you can handle validation errors locally within the controller through an `Errors` or `BindingResult` argument, as the following example shows:
>
> ```
> @PostMapping("/accounts")
> public void handle(@Valid @RequestBody Account account, BindingResult result) {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate, I am not using modelattribute annotation here.

Comment: Updated it's cited section.

Comment: "_Alternatively, you can handle validation errors locally within the controller through an Errors or BindingResult argument_"
Looks like you can either "handle it yourself" with `BindingResult`, or let Spring throw the Exceptions, which you can then catch.